# How to access laravel validation error in Vue.js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, validation

I'm using laravel 9 and Vue 3. I am trying to access laravel validation error in vue. Error message send by laravel.

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
errors: {supplyData.supplier_id: ["Please fill the supplier field"]}
supplyData.supplier_id: ["Please fill the supplier field"]
0: "Please fill the supplier field"
message: "The given data was invalid."
```

I have tried following code to access the error but it didn't work.

```
  <span
                    v-if="errors['supplyData.supplier_id']"
                   
                    class="invalid_feedback"
                    style="display:block; color:red;"
                    role="alert"
                >
                   {{ errors["supplyData.supplier_id"][0]}}
   </span>
```

Comment: Where is the errors coming from is it coming from an axios call?

Comment: yeah. And in backend i am using  laravel validation.

Comment: can you show your api call and handling @WhoDoYouthinkami

Comment: should i comment it or update the question?

Comment: Update it please. And can you share your response from backend

Comment: I also updated my answer @WhoDoYouthinkami, if it is true do not forget to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your console to see what is the real **response** from laravel backend, you probably see it is inside of data object,

Let's assume you have axios call like store()..

After this store request the data you got is response. The error is inside data of this response.

You can probably reach it like: response.data.errors

```
        .catch(error => {
            this.errors = error.response.data.errors; // this should be errors.
             console.log(this.errors);
        });
```